# WordPress - Image visible in the code but not in the website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a picture to a product in Wordpress Woocomerce and I can see the picture in the code when I use FireBug/Chrome DevTools.
But the picture is not visible in the website.
[image]

**Someone know why?**

Comment: Look at your css, maybe a ‘display:none; ‘ sets.

Comment: I don't see this parameter on my css...

Comment: Is there any js errors in the console?